# If cell begins with a certain 4 character move to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably a simple question for experts so apologies. I am new to VBA and have spent about 3 hours trying to figure this out by google searching. I was getting close and somehow lost my code when exiting excel.

So i have a spreadsheet that will vary in rows. It's a report that shows what version of a certain software all computers in the network are using. The report today has 30,000 rows.

There are 3 columns. A = computer name. B = Software name. C = software version.

The computer name consists of 3 letters, a dash and a name, making one word.

I am looking to have the macro look through the whole lot of column A rows and move the full rows of the column A that begins with for example ABC- and DEF- and XYZ- but to not copy MNO-.

I would like if it copied the computers for each branch to its own new sheet, so all computers that begin ABC- go to a sheet called ABC (no dash) and so on.

As i said i lost code that i had worked on so this is all i have so far, its a simple delete one that i've struggled to convert to a move one.

```
Sub MoveToNewSheet()
Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet
     For i = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
          If Left(.Cells(i, "A").Value, 4) = "DUB-" Then .Rows(i).Delete
     Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787328/looping-to-create-a-new-worksheet-for-each-new-data-in-a-row-ms-excel/28790475#28790475

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `Range.AutoFilter` method.

If your worksheet with all the data is named `Raw`, try the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub splitData()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, WS As Worksheet, WB As Workbook
    Dim rSrc As Range, rDest As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim cCol As Collection
    Dim I As Long, V As Variant
    Dim sPrefix As String

'set source worksheet and range
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSrc = WB.Worksheets("Raw")

'many ways to set the range
'may want to check that there is data on this worksheet
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsSrc.Cells) > 0 Then
    Set rSrc = wsSrc.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
Else
    MsgBox "No data on Raw worksheet"
    Exit Sub
End If

'get unique list of computer prefixes
Set cCol = New Collection
vSrc = rSrc.Columns(1) 'faster to loop through arrays

For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1) 'skip the header column
    sPrefix = Split(vSrc(I, 1), "-")(0)

    On Error Resume Next 'collection will error when try to store duplicate key
        cCol.Add Item:=sPrefix, Key:=sPrefix
    On Error GoTo 0
Next I
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'create new worksheets if needed
'copy relevant data to the new sheet
For Each V In cCol
    Set WS = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set WS = WB.Worksheets(V)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If WS Is Nothing Then
        Set WS = WB.Worksheets.Add(after:=WB.Worksheets(WB.Worksheets.Count))
        WS.Name = V
    End If

    rSrc.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    With rSrc
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=V & "-*", Operator:=xlAnd
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=WB.Worksheets(V).Cells(1, 1)
        .Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
Next V

End Sub
```

- Using a VBA array for speed, loop through all the computer names and get a collection of the unique computer prefixes

  - Loop through the collection, using the computer prefix to
  - Determine the destination sheet

    - create a sheet if it isn't there
  - Set an autofilter for "starts with" the computer prefix plus the hyphen
  - Copy the visible cells in the table to the new worksheet
  - Rinse and repeat

I did not delete anything from the raw data, in order to ensure things work, but, if you need to, you can easily add that to the code.